# Cordova build release cli

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, cordova-cli

As per Cordova documentation, why are the using iPhone Developer as codeSignIdentity for both debug and release? Is this correct or bug in documentation?

What I want is generate a .ipa file using CLI, that I can submit to iTunes Connect for distribution.

Ref: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

```
{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
        "packageType": "development",
        "buildFlag": [
            "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
            "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
            "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
        ]
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
        "packageType": "app-store",
        "buildFlag": [
            "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
            "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
            "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
        ]
    }
}
```

}

My build.json looks like this

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "packageType": "development",
            "developmentTeam": "MY-DEV-TEAM-ID"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "developmentTeam": "MY-DIST-TEAM-ID"
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using this command to do a build:

```
cordova build ios --device --release
```

Where will that distribution ready .ipa file get generated?